# Unswitched to switched outlet?

Tags: wiring

I recently replaced a switched outlet with a new receptacle. I was sure to wire it exactly as the old one. I also made sure to break the tab between the side screws where the red and black wires connect. However, upon turning the power back on, the outlet is still unswitched: power on both outlets and the wall switch has no affect. What am I missing?

Comment: If there are multiple outlets that are supposed to be switched and wired with the red and black then the tab must be broken on all.  One intact tab on a different outlet operated by the same switch can cause what your describing.

Comment: The tab you broke off, did you break it entirely off?  Are the nearby screws brass or silver colored?

Comment: Interesting. I didn't break it off all of them. And the screws are brass.

Answer (score 1):

First identify your switch leg. Turn off the power and disconnect the red and black wires and put wirenuts on the ends of them. Then turn the power back on using a non conducting power indicator, test the black and red for the wire that is permanently on. Then turning the switch off and on, identify the switch leg. Once you have done that then you know your wiring is connected properly to the box.

Now turn the power back off and reconnect the permanently hot conductor back to the receptacle. Check to see if only one part of the receptacle is working. If only one is working, kill power and connect the switch leg to the other side of the receptacle and verify it is correct.

Point being, you have isolated the problem to either the wiring or the receptacle and either one or the other is incorrect. If it's the receptacle then I would just replace it. If it's the wiring you may have to start tracing backwards to the switch.

Good luck

Comment: Hmm, interesting. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. I appreciate the detailed response!